Unique UserID in firebase email authentication in android development
I am using email authentication in firebase for authentication in my android application. I want to give users an unique userId, with which they can login later. Does firebase provide such system and How to implement this.
I am trying to store map of userID and email in firebase realtime database, to have userId verification.

Firebase doesn't have any features to assign unique usernames.  You would have to implement that yourself.  A complete description of how to do this is too long for a Stack Overflow answer.
